# Increasing number of predictions in Inception for Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am going through the training tutorial on retraining Inception's final layer after having installed Tensorflow for Ubuntu with regular CPU support. I successfully made the flower examples work however after switching to a new set of categories with ten sub-folders I cannot make Inception produce ten scores for each input image rather than the default five.  My current command line to run a test image looks like this, working with headers labelled 0-9.

> bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image && \
>   bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image \
>   --graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt \
>   --output_layer=final_result \ --input_layer=Mul
>   --image=$HOME/Input/Example.jpg

Which produces as a result

> 5 (4): 0.642959
>
> 3 (2): 0.243444
>
> 9 (8): 0.0513504
>
> 4 (5): 0.0231318
>
> 6 (7): 0.0180509

However I cannot find anything in the programs that Inception runs to reconfigure how many output scores are produced so that all ten of my categories have scores rather than just five. How do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with 8 categories and was able to get result for all of them.
If your code has below line

```
top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-5:][::-1]
```

change it to

```
top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]
```

If code contains `predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)` then use `predictions` instead of `predictions[0]`

I have run this using following command instead of bazel and I found it easier.

```
python /path_to_file/label_image.py /path_to_image/image.jpeg
```

First make sure that graph is created after you run `retrain.py` and it is at the correct location. (default is inside `/tmp/`).